# How to create a custom multifield for touch UI in CQ(AEM6)?

Tags: touch, aem

I already have a custom multifield in a component which works in classic UI(sidekick ) . However when i switch to touch UI mode, the custom multifield doesn't work. The dialog doesnt show anything, no "+" button to add the fields which I had designed in my custom multifield. Also, the dialog converter is unable to convert this custom multifield to the corresponding version for the touch UI.

Any ideas on how create a custom multifield in touch UI?

Comment: This can be helpful http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/03/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-coral-ui-nested-multi-multifield.html

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a multifield in Coral UI looks as follows:

```
<mymultifield
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
    fieldLabel="My multifield">
    <field
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
        name="./mymultifield" />
</mymultifield>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your dialog to cq:dialog following the documentation. Then you will be able to see you multifield component in touch ui.
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/dialog-conversion.html

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link.

Comment: you need to install the dialog conversion package in your cq instance then run for your particular component, it will create a touch ui dialog for you. And then just run your application in the editor.html mode. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by custom multifield, but if you mean a multifield of custom widgets, one thing you need to do is make sure your widget is part of the correct clientlib. I believe it's cq.widgets.